# Firing a solenoid with a timer only ONE SHOT rising edge trigger

Tags: transistors, solenoid

I have a button connected to 12V and want to fire a solenoid 24V ONCE every push of the button. No matter if the button is pushed 1 sec or one minute. The solenoid should fire more or less 1 sec and then go low EVEN if the button is still pressed. It's like a Trigger on the rising edge only. Is that text clear? I managed to do it with a microncontroller but I want to do it without a microcontroller. The examples using a 555 monostable with one shot didn't work if the button is still pressed (it keeps the solenoid ON until button is relased and I don't that that like that). Can you help with a solution with real values that I can simulate in Proteus? PS: I know it is a little off topics of this site. Thank you

Comment: Your description is fine as far as it goes.  Two things:  1) Do you have two power sources - a 12 V source for the control circuit, and a 24 V source to power the solenoid?  2) What is the solenoid coil power or current rating?

Comment: Hello. Two power sources. The solenoid is the Ford sw3 (the one used for pinball) I saw on youtube that he consumes 4amps +-. I wanted to use the IRL540 transistor. I hope this can help figuring this problem out.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that the solenoid must be ON for only 1 second every rising edge only.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a 555 and your power transistor, but you have to add a small signal transistor and differentiator circuit to the Trigger input

One alternative is a CMOS logic quad gate such as a CD4093 instead of the 555. It is a larger part, but the overall circuit has fewer soldered pins.

UPDATE:

Here is a first-pass concept schematic of a CD4093 monostable and driver.  Component values are approximate.  The timing period is a little under 1 s, and can be modified by changing R2.  Because this is a true monostable (incorporating positive feedback), an input differentiator is not needed.

Standard CMOS logic devices can run on anything from 3 V to 15-18 V. The input transition level is approx. 50% of Vdd. The 4093 has hysteretic inputs, so there are two transition levels at approx. 40% and 60% of Vdd. Note that 60% is about 5% less than one time constant (63.2%), so the timing period will be a bit less than one time constant.  Also, the transition levels are not tightly controlled in production, and vary with temperature more than the levels in a 555.

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/50862/FAIRCHILD/CD4093.html

[image]

As a reference, here is the 555 circuit with the added input differentiator (R3-C3).  Note that neither circuit has switch debouncing.  Click on each image for a larger view.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Odd that doesn't work in Proteus. Am I doing something wrong? I can't insert the image I grabbed from Proteus.

Comment: Hello. I had and error in my schematics. The cap was not polarised. Changed it and .... IT WORKS! Thanks. You're the best!

Comment: If you are talking about the timing capacitor C2, it does not need to be a polarized type like an electrolytic.  A high-value ceramic capacitor will work just fine IRL.  If you do use a polarized cap, it must be connected as indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.

[image]

Optimum resistor and capacitor values are to be determined through simulation / trials.

Comment: The solenoid releases immediately when the button is released.  The TS requires that the solenoid stay energized even if the button is released before 1 second has elapsed.  Also, the relay image is incorrect.

Comment: @AnalogKid - Hi! Thank you very much for your feedback. The relay symbol has been corrected. However, the OP does not specifically mention push button release but does lay emphasis on keeping it pressed - 'No matter if the button is pushed 1 sec or one minute. The solenoid should fire more or less 1 sec and then go low EVEN if the button is still pressed.'

Comment: @AnalogKid The problems I see are: 1) CD4093 can he get 12V input in nand gate? 2) How come that Proteus in the gate of the mosfet tell's me that 1V is applied to the gate. 1V? Shouldn't it be 5V?

Comment: See the up-updated answer.

Comment: Hi Guys and thanks for the replies so far. So far, the circuit of @AnalogKid CD4093 is the one that works in Proteus so I ordered on CD4093 to test the circuit IN VIVO. In Proteus, the gate of the mosfet only get 1V. Maybe it's a Proteus mislcalculation.

Comment: If you are talking about Q1 (reference designators work only if you use them), it sees a full 12 V swing from U1D.  Not that my schematic software hides power and GND connections to logic devices.  Make sure your sim has them.  Also, Q1 can be replaced with a bipolar NPN transistor if you add a base resistor.

Comment: @AnalogKid Yes Q1. Sorry. I can't read the datasheets very well. Q1 has Vgs=10V. 1) So it need 10V in the gate to saturate and let the 24V go to the solenoid? 2) I can't see in the datasheet of CD4093 where the input for the pins (nands) Voltage is? 12V just like the VDD for the chip? Sorry for the dumb questions. I just have thos doubts, the rest I got it. Thanks

Comment: Most power MOSFETs have the same 10 V rating.  This is the voltage that guarantees the minimum Rdson (on-state resistance, similar to saturation in a bipolar transistor).  Also, the max gate voltage spec probably is 20 V, so 12 V fits in nicely between the two.

Comment: THANKS! I'm ordering the components to build the circuit.